# Error con promesas " Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') "

Tags: javascript, fetch

Necesito recorrer los datos que que obtuve mediante `fetch()` para así poder devolver el valor de un boleto de autobús, dependiendo de los km recorridos. En el archivo del fetch están los valores por km.

Este es mi código:

```
function cargarBoletos() {
    fetch('boletos.json')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            return data;
        })
}

let valor = 0;
async function retornarValor(km, tarifa_social) {
    let boleto = await cargarBoletos();
    let i = 0;
    while (i < 4) {
        if (km <= boleto[i].km_max) {
            if (tarifa_social == true) {
                valor = boleto[i].tarifa;
            } else { valor = boleto[i].pasaje; }
            break;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }

    if (km >= 28) {
        if (tarifa_social == true) {
            valor = 10.35;
        } else { valor = 23 }
    }
    return valor;
}
```

Llamo a `retornarValor` con otra función, donde hay una variable `let valor_boleto = retornarValor(km, tarifa_social);` y de ahí creo un div que muestra los datos por pantalla.

El tema, es que me salta este error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') at retornarValor

y en pantalla se muestra "El viaje te salió $[objet Promise]".

En la consola, en el objeto me sale:

```
valor_boleto: Promise
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "rejected"
[[PromiseResult]]: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') at retornarValor
```

Comment: Bienvenido Abi. Me suena a que el error que experimentas, se debe a que en algún momento de tu bucle, `boletos[i]` es `undefined`, y estas intentando leer propiedades (`tarifa`, `pasaje`) de un objeto indefinido

Comment: Pareciera ser que [esta respuesta](/a/346461) guarda relación con tu pregunta. Prueba a ver qué tal.

Comment: Pude resolver como hacer para que lea correctamente las propiedades y corra el ciclo. En vez de salirme reject ahora me sale fulfilled, pero igualmente sigue mostrando la object promise y no el valor.